# How to use env markers in include variable of poetry packaging?

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have some binaries that are a part of the source code. Based on the OS and architecture of the system, I want to include them in source distribution and python wheel. Using `TOML` file format and `poetry` packaging tool, how can this be achieved?

Tried the following:

```ini
include = [
    { path = "my_proj/ffmpeg_bin/ffmpeg_windows_amd64", format = ["sdist", "wheel"], markers = "platform_machine == 'amd64' and platform_system == 'Windows'" },
    { path = "my_proj/ffmpeg_bin/ffmpeg_linux_aarch64", format = ["sdist", "wheel"], markers = "platform_machine == 'aarch64' and platform_system == 'Linux'" },
    { path = "my_proj/ffmpeg_bin/ffmpeg_linux_x86_64", format = ["sdist", "wheel"], markers = "platform_machine == 'x86_64' and platform_system == 'Linux'" },
    { path = "my_proj/ffmpeg_bin/ffmpeg_darwin_x86_64", format = ["sdist", "wheel"], markers = "platform_machine == 'x86_64' and platform_system == 'Darwin'" },
    { path = "my_proj/ffmpeg_bin/ffmpeg_darwin_arm64", format = ["sdist", "wheel"], markers = "platform_machine == 'arm64' and platform_system == 'Darwin'" },
    { path = "my_proj/ffmpeg_bin/ffmpeg_android_aarch64", format = ["sdist", "wheel"], markers = "platform_machine == 'aarch64' and platform_system == 'Android'" }
]
```

On running `poetry check` on the pyproject.toml, an invalid configuration error is thrown with an invalid schema reasoning.
The above use case is also [not supported](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1728) in `setup.cfg` configured using `setuptools` (*In `setup.cfg`, this is configured under the `option.package_data` section*).

[Poetry doc](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers) says it supports `env markers` as per [PEP-508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers) for managing dependencies.

Is there a way I can achieve this using `poetry`?

Comment: You'll likely need to define your own `build.py` see: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/8460 ; What you have are not _dependencies_, they're _distributions_.